# Target 2nd child in ul

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would need to target 2nd child in my UL. Here is my html code and styles applied

HTML:

```
<ul class="latestpost">
    <li class="clearfix">
        <time datetime="2014-10-22T19:33">22<span class="month">Oct</span></time>
        <h4><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Title</a></h4>
        <div class="excerpt">
            sometxt...
        </div>
    </li>

    /*I want to target bg of this li below, it is also li of the same ul as first li in my html */
    <li class="clearfix">
        <time datetime="2014-10-22T09:16">22<span class="month">Oct</span></time>
        <h4><a href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to title</a></h4>
        <div class="excerpt">
            sometxt...
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.latestpost li time {
        background:#d5176f;     
        border-right: 1px solid #d5176f;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d5176f;
        color:#fff;
}
ul.latestpost li time:nth-child(2) {
        background:red !important;      
        border-right: 1px solid #d5176f;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d5176f;
        color:#fff !important;
}
```

Struggling for some time now, but I know it's a simple fix. Any advise is welcome

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please format your markup so it is more readable.  Also, can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do?  Are you trying to select the li tag with javascript?

Comment: Something to note, using `:nth-child(even)` and `:nth-child(odd)` will do away with the need to use important and less repetition of code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the second `<time>` element, but the second **`<li>`** element that you're targetting. So, use these rules :

```
.latestpost li time {
    ...
}
.latestpost li:nth-child(2) time {
    ...
}
```

*Sidenote : please fix these broken  tags*

Answer (score 0):

To target the second child of your `ul` you would use:

```
ul.latestpost li:nth-child(2) {

}
```

But looking at your current CSS I think you want to target the `time` in the second `li`:

```
ul.latestpost li:nth-child(2) time {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your selector is wrong. Currently you're looking for the 2nd `time` element in each of your `li`. As each of your `li` elements only contain one `time` element there is nothing to apply the style to. If you're trying to select the 2nd `time` element in your example I believe your selector will need to be as follows

```
ul.latestpost li:nth-child(2) time { ... }
```